# Lack of revision note and cc-wiki graphic in Ubuntu footer

Tags: discussion, design

I noticed today that the Ubuntu site doesn't appear to have the cc-wiki graphic and "revision" note that usually appears in the Stack Exchange footer. I don't want to tag this as a bug, but I was wondering if the omission of that design feature was intentional?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is now a creative commons graphic in the footer of both the main site and meta.